# Chrome Extension: "No resource with given identifier found" when trying to Network.getResponseBody

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome Extension that can get HTTP response for a site. I try to use debugger for getting response body:

```js
var gCurrentTab;

chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function (source, method, params) {
        if (gCurrentTab.id != source.tabId) {
            return;
        }
        if (method == "Network.loadingFinished") {
            var tabId = source.tabId;
            var requestId = params.requestId;
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
                source,
                "Network.getResponseBody",
                {"requestId": requestId},
                function (body) {
                    console.log(body);
                    chrome.debugger.detach(source);
                });
        }
    }
);

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
        var url = details.url;
        if (url.indexOf('/mypage') >= 0) {
            chrome.tabs.query({
                currentWindow: true,
                active: true
            }, function (tabs) {
                gCurrentTab = tabs[0];
                chrome.debugger.attach({
                    tabId: gCurrentTab.id
                }, "1.0", function () {
                    chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                        tabId: gCurrentTab.id
                    }, "Network.enable");
                });
            });
        }
    },
    {urls: []}, ["requestBody", "blocking"]);
```

But I always get

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running debugger.sendCommand: {"code":-32000,"message":"No resource with given identifier found"}
at chrome-extension://ikphgobkghdkjkfplgokmapjlbdfeegl/background.js:11:29

error, and the body is undefined.

Does anyone have idea about why this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was because the website sends many responses, and this code will see another request other than I want, then detach the debugger so I can't get the result.

To solve this, just use a single debugger and do not detach it, or only detach when it's safe to.

```js
var gAttached = false;
var gRequests = [];
var gObjects = [];

chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function (source, method, params) {
        if (method == "Network.requestWillBeSent") {
            // If we see a url need to be handled, push it into index queue
            var rUrl = params.request.url;
            if (getTarget(rUrl) >= 0) {
                gRequests.push(rUrl);
            }
        }
        if (method == "Network.responseReceived") {
            // We get its request id here, write it down to object queue
            var eUrl = params.response.url;
            var target = getTarget(eUrl);
            if (target >= 0) {
                gObjects.push({
                    requestId: params.requestId,
                    target: target,
                    url: eUrl
                });
            }
        }
        if (method == "Network.loadingFinished" && gObjects.length > 0) {
            // Pop out the request object from both object queue and request queue
            var requestId = params.requestId;
            var object = null;
            for (var o in gObjects) {
                if (requestId == gObjects[o].requestId) {
                    object = gObjects.splice(o, 1)[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Usually loadingFinished will be immediately after responseReceived
            if (object == null) {
                console.log('Failed!!');
                return;
            }
            gRequests.splice(gRequests.indexOf(object.url), 1);
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
                source,
                "Network.getResponseBody",
                {"requestId": requestId},
                function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        dispatch(source.tabId, object.target, JSON.parse(response.body));
                    } else {
                        console.log("Empty response for " + object.url);
                    }
                    // If we don't have any request waiting for response, re-attach debugger
                    // since without this step it will lead to memory leak.
                    if (gRequests.length == 0) {
                        chrome.debugger.detach({
                            tabId: source.tabId
                        }, function () {
                            chrome.debugger.attach({
                                tabId: source.tabId
                            }, "1.0", function () {
                                chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                                    tabId: source.tabId
                                }, "Network.enable");
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    }
);

var initialListener = function (details) {
    if (gAttached) return;  // Only need once at the very first request, so block all following requests
    var tabId = details.tabId;
    if (tabId > 0) {
        gAttached = true;
        chrome.debugger.attach({
            tabId: tabId
        }, "1.0", function () {
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                tabId: tabId
            }, "Network.enable");
        });
        // Remove self since the debugger is attached already
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(initialListener);
    }
};

// Attach debugger on startup
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(initialListener, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking"]);

// Filter if the url is what we want
function getTarget(url) {
    for (var i in TARGETS) {
        var target = TARGETS[i];
        if (url.match(target.url)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

const TARGETS = [
    {url: '/path1', desc: 'target1'},
    {url: '/path2', desc: 'target2'}
]
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate on this?
I face the same problem but can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: Here you are. The point is you need to use correct request id, and with the same debugger.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it's possible that the request has not finished yet. You could try `import time;time.sleep(5)` before getResponseBody.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue. I figured that sendCommand was not executing immediately. I was facing the issue for the requests which are sent before sending "Network.enable" was complete. Try adding completion for

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                        tabId: gCurrentTab.id
                    }, "Network.enable")
```